# To handle emitted events from solidity in javascript in truffle suite

Tags: web3js, ethereum-wallet-dapp, ethereumjs

The function I am accessing will emit events i need to use that event but the function is a transaction when i am accessing the event it turns as promise pending . So suggest me some methods. thanks!

Please find my code below

```
App.contracts.Sample.deployed().then(function(instance) {
    mainInstance = instance;
    instance.countPlayers().then(function(count) {
        console.log(count.valueOf()) // returning values 
    })

    // to access events emitted
    instance.onlineCount({}, {  
        fromBlock: 0,
        toBlock: 'latest'
    }).watch(function(error, event) {
       console.log("event---->", event) /// promise pending error
       App.render();
    })
});
```

Comment: Use `await` or resolve the promise.

Comment: App.contracts.Sample.deployed().then(function(instance) {  }) . How can i call my event with deployed instance. i can able to access a return function but not event

Comment: You should write your question properly (**including any relevant code**) in the designated area, not in comments.

Answer (score 0):

I can give you an example of how I did something similar:

First I create a variable to hold the desired output of the event. In my case it is an address of a newly created contract:

```
var TargetAddress;
```

Then I create a listener for the event and get the address from the response of the event:

```
var event = instance.TargetCreated(function(error, response) {
    if (!error) {
        TargetAddress = response.args.addr;
    }else{
        console.log(error);
    }
});
```

You can also just "console.log()" the response to see what you get as a return.

Then I await the method invocation:

```
await protocol.registerMitigator(MitigatorOwner,1000,"Mitigator1",{from: TargetOwner});
```

And right afterwards I make my assertions as follows:

```
return await IActor.at(MitigatorAddress).then(async function(owner) {
assert.equal(MitigatorOwner, await owner.getOwner(), "Mitigator Address is wrong");
});
```

---

All set together it looks like this:

```
it("Mitigator Creation", async function() {

        var MitigatorAddress;

        return await Protocol.deployed().then(async function(instance) {          
            //Get the deployed protocol instance
            //Define the fallback for the event which gives us the address of the created mitigator
            var event = instance.MitigatorCreated(function(error, response) {
                if (!error) {
                    MitigatorAddress = response.args.addr;
                }else{
                    console.log(error);
                }
            });

            await instance.registerMitigator(MitigatorOwner,1000,"Mitigator1", {from: TargetOwner});
            return await IActor.at(MitigatorAddress).then(async function(owner) { 
                assert.equal(MitigatorOwner, await owner.getOwner(), "Mitigator address is wrong");
            });
        });
    });
```

Hope I could give you some inputs with this :)